# wrong characters á é í ñ in python spark notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, character

I'm loading some twitters with the spanish characters á,é,í...ñ, and apparently they are well stored but when I load them in a RDD using notebook an python, these letters are substituted by \xe1, \xe9 .. and so on.

Example:

u'RT @rodriguezjoma: El #petr\xf3leo y #Repsol fracasan en su intento de superar resistencias: https://t.co/EtmZynrxQG https://t.co/JQcG5gk4Cd',
u'Metele Marc que quiero ver a la naranjita repsol con el #1 este a\xf1o!!!',

What can I do to get the right characters?

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct characters, but the representation of a unicode string uses escape sequences for characters outside the ASCII range.